# Configure dynamic header value for Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have imported an API to Azure APIM. I have to specify the header details on APIM. May I know, how can I do this ?

Note : I have tried adding policy for that API as mentioned on below URL, but this is static value. For my case I need to pass dynamic values/different values to header.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request.md

Thanks,
Infaaz

Comment: Share snippert of you code.. to better understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You can have dynamic headers in your APIM policy. We support expressions in policies

```
<set-header name="x-request-context-data" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(context.User.Id)</value>
</set-header>
```

from [sample](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/blob/master/policies/Send%20context%20information%20to%20the%20backend%20service.policy.xml#L7)

please take a look at everything that is exposed on context object [policy expressions context object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables)

You can read about it [Set HttpHeader policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader)